# How can we test the MotionEvent touch action in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How can we UI test the view which is having a motion event action. Ex. verify the text ("View Presses") displayed while view is pressed

```
Box(modifier= Modifier
        .clip(clipShape)
        .pointerInteropFilter { event->
            when(event.action){
                MotionEvent.ACTION_Down->{
                    Log.d("Touches", "View Presses")
                } 
                else { Log.d("Touches", "View Not Pressed")}
            }
            true
        }
    ){...}
```